# <li> not adopting css class (override it?)

Tags: css, plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/10Xx2dkqPBeK24cEFVtC?p=preview

```
<li class="language-list">
```

`li` doesn't seem to want to adopt my css class:

```
.language-list, li.language-list {
  height:50px;
  background: silver;
}
```

Check the Plunkr for a full example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jg8g8ufw). You're just not linking to your CSS file yet. In Plunkr, html files are full files, so you need to include a `<link rel="" href="" type="">` line.

[Here's an updated working Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/plWgMAPq57j4za3RCTrR?p=preview)

```css
ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0em;
}
.language-list, li.language-list {
  height:50px;
  background: silver;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-ng-bind="data.language.next" data-ng-click="profilePage()" class="btn btn-lg btn-success center-block">

</button>

<ol class="scroll">
    <li style="height:50px; background: silver;">
        <div style="height:100%; width:10%; float:left; background: red;">
            <img src="http://www.wwf.hu/images/zaszlo_en1.png">
        </div>
        <div data-ng-bind="lang.languageInLanguage" style="height:100%; width:10%; float:left; background: pink;">
          english
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="language-list">
        <div style="height:100%; width:10%; float:left; background: red;">
            <img src="http://www.wwf.hu/images/zaszlo_en1.png">
        </div>
        <div data-ng-bind="lang.languageInLanguage" style="height:100%; width:10%; float:left; background: pink;">
          english
        </div>
    </li>
</ol>
```